# Water damage or bad patch job on the ceiling directly under the shower stall of master bath?

Tags: water-damage, patching-drywall

We moved in 2 years ago into a new build. Just today I’ve noticed this discoloration on the ceiling. Directly above it is the master bath shower stall.

My husband thinks this is a bad patch work. I’m just a little worried since we are both first time home owner and both not very handy at all.

I  would like second/third opinions from someone that is more knowledgeable than us.

[image]

Comment: It's a bit difficult to tell from a photo but it looks like water damage to me.  I don't like coincidences so the fact that it's below a shower leads me to strongly suspect water leaking.  The only way to tell for sure is to inspect it.  You might try some moisture % reading with a meter and a "borescope" through a small hole before you start opening up drywall.

Comment: The fact that you can see an outline of what looks like a panel removed is also suspicious.  Perhaps there was a previous leak prior to your taking possession and they "patched" it.

Comment: Is there a shape to it or is it just color? Could just need a good primer and paint.

Comment: Then I bet it was opened to repair plumbing and patched back in. Whether there was water present isn't terribly relevant at this point. Single incidents aren't usually a long-term problem.

Comment: @jwh20 thank you for your input. I suspect it’s water damage too since it’s below the shower. We will get someone out to inspect it just in case... it’s very suspicious since we’re the first owner of this home. Very disappointed with the work/builder so far. Sigh

Comment: @isherwood there is a double square imprint to it leading to it. But what I’m not sure is would the imprint show up over time without moisture there? Sorry if I sound silly. I don’t have much knowledge in this field. Not quite so sure how it works...

Comment: Hard to say. I interpret the double stain as being drywall mud with paper tape down the middle. You'll need to investigate to determine whether it's damp. Chances are it will feel colder than the surrounding area, or you could use a device to check humidity.

Comment: Is there any kind of access panel that you can use to get a look at the shower plumbing and drain pipe, etc. for inspection? Looking again at the patch... could it be that the compound wasn't finished the same as the rest of the ceiling and the color difference is a function of the dissimilar materials, lack of primer, or differences in texture/reflectivity under the ceiling paint?

Comment: As others note, it is 100% a patch, possibly due to a leak, and might still be leaking.  But I would bet that square part of the discoloration is due to the patch and paint job (no primer, only one coat of paint, etc), not a current leak, as you wouldn't have water travelling equally along that gap to produce uniform discoloration like that. 
That said, the picture makes it look like there might be a spot of minor water leak toward the top (of the picture) outside of the square. Might just be the picture or it might be another anomaly of the bad patch & paint job.

Answer (score 1):

It is both.  Probably.

A section of drywall was removed to fix a leak.
Perhaps the leak has returned and now moisture has migrated into the seams of the resectioned area causing discoloration. However user DMoore has never seen such a thing and his reputation is beyond reproach.

So it could be that a section of drywall was left out during drywall install to leave access to the underside of a shower that had not yet been hooked up.
This was done in my house when the plumber was on vacation and the drywall installation had to proceed.

To be certain that it is active leak use a moisture meter to determine that this area is significantly higher in moisture content than other areas in the ceiling.

If it is wet  a similar cut out will need to be made so that whatever is leaking( most likely  the drain) can be fixed.  Then a new patch can be made.

Followed with a stain blocking primer and repaint the ceiling.

Comment: This is obviously not the right answer.   If there were water damage the ceiling would be yellow and have spotting.   There would not be a tape line around the patch that was put there.   This is not right - you should remove this.   I have never seen a water stain in my life that is a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

As a new build. I would say if it started showing now it is a leak.

if it were a bad patch job it would have been visible from day 1.

A little moisture not enough to spot comes through at a seam, they may have had a leak when testing the drains so a piece was cut out to repair.

It is possible now it may have a small leak again showing at the repair.

The patch looks tight and in good shape so it is not a bad patch or in my opinion it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

It is a less than perfect patch job - it's even and rectangular in shape. Leaks are round. You can clearly see the taped and compounded areas. Now, that being said...it's indicative of someone needing access to the drain - either due to a leak or needing access to disconnect an old tub's drain assembly.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the stain slowly just showed up so it is likely to be water from a leaky tile job, drain, or pipe fitting.  These can work their way apart as a new house begins to shift and move a bit.  It is also likely the square shape is from a  patch, but the water is the cause or the stain and the patch is just where it revealed itself.  Typically water from the floor above will find its way through a floor assembly and accumulate in the low spots between drywall panels. The exposed ceiling face is smooth, but the back is a crevice that provides a low spot for water to pool in and slowly move through to the face of the drywall. The shower sounds like the place to start looking, but sometimes water can be deceiving as it will show up a long way from the source if it has a sloped element like a pipe, duct, or truss member to follow downward.  It can also be from condensation on uninsulated pipes, ducts, or exterior walls.  Call your contractor to have them find the definitive source of the water, but do not do any patching, or painting before as it will only be harder to trace it back to the source.